# Seems that Thread.start () does a notify ()

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor

I've just found strange behavior in java threads.
Here is a code example:

```
class Job extends Thread {
    private Integer number = 0;
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
            number++;
        }
    }
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InterruptedException {
        Job thread = new Job();
        thread.start();
        synchronized (thread) {
            thread.wait();
        }
        System.out.println(thread.getNumber());
    }
}
```

Unexpectedly it'll print out the 999999. 
Seems like there is *notify()* call at the end of *start()*  method logic. 
Any ideas?

Comment: And why wouldn't it print `999999`? `number` is incremented that many times only. Check it out for smaller loop ranges.

Comment: Because there is *thread.wait()*

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, you've got a race condition, where the thread where the Test runs is calling start() then calling wait(), but there is no guarantee that wait() will occur instantaneously after start().  Your Test class' thread could block after start(), then your Job thread could run for any amount of time before your Test class calls wait().  If you want to wait instantly, you should consider calling wait() from within Job.run()...

Comment: If you call notify() when nothing is wait()ing it is ignored.  This means if it were called as a part of start() it would be discarded. i.e. a thread cannot notify itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Seems like there is notify() call at the end of start() method logic.

Yes, this is true.  When a thread finishes it does a `notify()` which is how `Thread.join()` works.  Here's a sample of the Java1.6 code for `Thread.join()`:

```
public final synchronized void join(long millis) throws InterruptedException {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = 0;
    if (millis < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }
    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
    } else {
            ...
```

That said, this may be implementation dependent and should not be relied on.